# How can i detect any version in my app?

Tags: java, android

I'm create app with SDK 1.6 and i want to, if my app running in android 3 : do sth , i using these code but the error told me `HONEYCOMB` cannot be resolved or is not a field.

here is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE == Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
// do anything...
} else {
// do anything...
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For `Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` to be recognized at compile time, you will need to have your build target set to API Level 11 or higher. In Eclipse, this is in the Android section of your project properties; for command-line builds, this is in `default.properties`.

Comment: So how we can do that in SDK 1.6?

Comment: @Jack: If you compile with a build target of API Level 11 or higher, the `HONEYCOMB` integer will be "inlined" in the bytecode. The actual symbol is never referenced at runtime. Hence, this specific code will work on any version of Android. Here is a sample project where I do this very comparison for the purposes of tailoring the action bar on Honeycomb: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC

Comment: Okay sir, But let me told my problem clearly , well i made app for android , and all my layout orientation set as Portrait, i want to if my app running in HONEYCOMB the orientation set as Landscape.

Comment: @Jack: Call [`setRequestedOrientation()`](http://goo.gl/uTP4P) and wait for your users to give you one-start ratings on the Market for not supporting portrait on tablets. Personally, I suggest that you simply support both orientations.

Comment: yup i agree with you , I'm regretful , WXVGA is for Honeycomb in res 1280*800 for landscape , and what's the res in potrait mode for Honeycomb?

Comment: @Jack: WXVGA is WXVGA for any device, any OS. WXVGA is what is known as a "resolution". It is 1280x800 or 800x1280, depending on how you hold it. There is no "resolution" for an Android OS version like Honeycomb.